# heroku throwing bourbon `Undefined mixin 'transform'`

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, bourbon

i'm deploying a rails 4 app to heroku, getting

```
Running: rake assets:precompile
   I, [2013-10-31T13:50:45.980969 #699]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_66fd87fd-a9f1-442b-88b3-ccbc9f7f6e28/public/assets/application-ffa1a91721fb49b9c6414032f35a7045.js
   rake aborted!
   Undefined mixin 'transform'.
   (in /tmp/build_66fd87fd-a9f1-442b-88b3-ccbc9f7f6e28/app/assets/stylesheets/main.css.scss:29)
   /tmp/build_66fd87fd-a9f1-442b-88b3-ccbc9f7f6e28/app/assets/stylesheets/main.css.scss:29:in `transform'
   /tmp/build_66fd87fd-a9f1-442b-88b3-ccbc9f7f6e28/app/assets/stylesheets/main.css.scss:29
```

everything is working locally including the style that mixin is associate with so I'm confused about this.  Not seeing much documentation on google:foo about what the problem is.  I've got

```
  config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

in application.rb

Any thoughts on what to do here ?

Answer (score -1):

It looks like your `application.css.scss` includes a `main.css.scss` which references `bourbon` mixins. You need add `@import 'bourbon'` to the top of your `main.css.scss` file and any other `scss` file that references the mixins.